Gratis Windows command line app to delete all lines in a text file which contain a given string
I am trying to see the wood for the trees in a very large log file. There are several sets of oft repeated lines which I would like to delete, in order to make things more legible.
I can do it with Notepad++ by bookmarking all lines containing such strings and then deleting all bookmarked lines, but would p[refer a command line tool.
Before I knock up a quick python script, is there something existing?
Must be gratis. Must be a built-in command or portable app as I am locked down & unable to install new software.
Just removelines log.txt foo or removelines log.txt foo bar, to remove lines containing "foo" or either "foo" or "bar". I would prefer not to have to use regular expressions for ... reasons

I don't see any reasons not too use regexes for this, but they aren't even needed within text processing tools for such simple task. For example, you could use classic grep like this:
grep -v something log.txt > log.txt

where -v means checking for lines that don't contain the phrase.
For 2 lines a basic alternative regex something|else is needed, but you could just run the command above twice with different words if you really really don't want regexes.
